# Calling bteq from Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, teradata

I currently generate a bat file that contains multiple BTEQ calls to execute a .btq script against a Teradata box, below is an example CMD call:

```
bteq <Bteq\"File_1.BTQ" >>bteq_output.txt 2>&1
```

The syntax as far as I understand it is:

**>** specifies the input file & **>>** specifies the output file

I am currently trying to convert the bat implementation to a PowerShell version however I get stuck with the following issue:

```
PS C:\...\Deploy.ps1:21 char:81
+ ... -Object { bteq < (Join-Path $deployDir $_) >> bteq_log.txt }
+                    ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [],ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

Which is the result of this call in my PowerShell script:

```
(Get-Content -Path $configFile) | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { bteq.exe < (Join-Path $deployDir $_) >> bteq_output.txt }
```

It seems that the BTEQ command line syntax directly conflicts with the **<** operator in PowerShell.

**EDIT**
If I try to escape the < with ` then instead I am presented with the following error, as though the parameter is not picked up:

```
bteq.exe :  *** Warning: You must log on before sending SQL requests. 
At C:\...\Deploy.ps1:20 char:76
+ (Get-Content -Path $configFile) | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { bteq. ...
+                                                                            ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ( *** Warning: Y... SQL requests. :String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Anyone able to shed any light as to how one would call a bteq command in PowerShell when specifying the file to be used?

Comment: Maybe escape it, using the grave-accent character (  `  )?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't seem to want to be picked up as an input command for the bteq call. When I have `< I get this error:

    bteq.exe :  *** Warning: You must log on before sending SQL requests. 
At C:....Deploy.ps1:20 char:76
+ (Get-Content -Path $configFile) | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { bteq. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in powershell 
try `cat <your-bteq-file> | bteq` to call your bteq file

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks for the post.

I have altered the statement to cater for all files in the chosen directory and ended up with this:

Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | foreach { Get-Content (Join-Path $dir $_) | bteq >> output.txt 2>&1 }

Comment: Can you explain what this results it?  I'm actually now having the same issue in VBScript.  I can use the < character, BTEQ acts like everything after bteq isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to wrap the portion in your `foreach` into a script block and PowerShell will treat it as one command. You would just need to begin with the `&` symbol.

```
foreach { & {bteq.exe < (Join-Path $deployDir $_) >> bteq_output.txt} }
```

Not being at a machine to test this you might have to dynamically build the script block as a string so your variable is resolved correctly from the loop.

Comment: Same issue I am afraid, the '<' character is still recognized as a special char in $PS. Using the ` before in the statement you wrote has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to seeing the answer posted by Shailesh, I managed to get it working via a call to cmd as follows:

```
(Get-Content -Path $configFile)[1..$fileCount] | ForEach-Object {     
    cmd.exe /C ([String]::Concat(" bteq <", $deployDir, "`\""" , $_ , """ >>output.txt 2>&1"))
    if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0){
        Write-Host "Error Code" $LASTEXITCODE
        break
    } else {
        Write-Host "Completed" $_ ": Return code" $LASTEXITCODE
    }
};
```

Here this set of statement iterates over the text read from the $configFile variable, and then makes a call to bteq for each one breaking if an error code is not equal to 0.